# How to take thumbnail screenshots of websites using PHP?

Tags: php, api, screenshot, thumbnails

I have just read through lots of articles about how to create thumbnail screenshots and haven't found anything reliable.

Is there an api I can simply enter the url of the website I want to take a screenshot of and have it returned as an image using PHP?

Comment: how many thumbnails do you need to generate? do you care if you use an external service? are you willing to pay if nec? or do you need to have this capability running on your own servers?

Comment: [ApiFlash](https://apiflash.com) is pretty reliable and has a PHP example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out http://www.thumbalizr.com/apitools.php

Here's an example: http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=http://www.google.com.au&width=250

It's very easy to use, and has a free plan for small use cases with other plans that should meet more advanced or demanding needs. Of course, there are hundreds of other services. But Thumbalizer is the most popular (according to Google) and is very easy to use.

Comment: We've used thumbalizr before and it is not a good service to use if you can't deal with their downtime issues.  We ended up abandoning them in favour of some other service I forget, following excessive downtime.  I think we use these now: http://webthumb.bluga.net/home, but we still have issues with them, so if anyone has an better services I'm keen to see them :)

Comment: Yeah, all services like this are pretty resource demanding, and most free services will not be very reliable. If resources permit, it's always better to roll your own. But for most use cases, that is too complicated and not worth it. This space could definitely use with some more robust and reliable tools.

Comment: If you add to roll your own, what would you use to do it? I know about PhantomJS but that would require running something like NodeJS obthe server side (since we're building an API). Would be great to find something that we could use from Go.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be surprised how many screenshot automation APIs there are out there: Here's a nice little article comparing five major providers: **[Screenshot API Comparison Site](http://freescreenshotapi.com)**.

Major differences between the APIs are the cost-per-screenshot, rendering speed and image quality, and most of them return the screenshot directly via the request URL.

Plus, there's a [PHP code example](http://freescreenshotapi.com/capture-screenshot) on the same site.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  http://www.screenshotmachine.com service. It has a simple HTTP GET based API. Here is the documentation page: http://www.screenshotmachine.com/apiguide.php

Answer (score 2):

You can make your screenshot API with:

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/documentation/)

or:

[SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of open source projects that can generate website screenshots and thumbnails that can be called from PHP. For example PhantomJS, webkit2png etc

The big problem with these projects is that they are based on older browser technology and have problems rendering many sites, especially sites that use webfonts, flexbox, svg and various other additions to the HTML5 and CSS spec over the last couple of months/years.

I've tried a few of the third party services, and most are based on PhantomJS, meaning they also produce poor quality screenshots. The best third party service for generating website screenshots is [urlbox.io](https://urlbox.io). It is a paid service, although there is a free 7-day trial to test it out without committing to any paid plan.

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://urlbox.io/docs), and below are simple steps to get it working in PHP with composer. If you're not using composer just copy the code from the [github repo](https://github.com/urlbox-io/urlbox-screenshots-php/blob/master/src/Urlbox.php)

```
// 1 . Get the urlbox/screenshots composer package (on command line):
composer require urlbox/screenshots

// 2. Set up the composer package with Urlbox API credentials:
$urlbox = UrlboxRenderer::fromCredentials('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET');

// 3. Set your options (all options such as full page/full height screenshots, retina resolution, viewport dimensions, thumbnail width etc can be set here. See the docs for more.)
$options['url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235638/how-to-take-thumbnail-screenshots-of-websites-using-php'; // set url to this very page!
$options['thumb_width'] = 400; // set thumbnail to be 400px wide
$options['full_page'] = true; // set full_page mode on, will instruct urlbox to take a full height screenshot

// 4. Generate the Urlbox url
$urlboxUrl = $urlbox->generateUrl($options);
// $urlboxUrl is now 'https://api.urlbox.io/v1/ca482d7e-9417-4569-90fe-80f7c5e1c781/0ad1be1ff7ac16bc295d8b0207c98e776003e53e/png?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4235638%2Fhow-to-take-thumbnail-screenshots-of-websites-using-php&full_page=true&thumb_width=400'

// 5. Now stick it in an img tag, when the image is loaded in browser, the API call to urlbox will be triggered and a nice PNG screenshot will be generated!
<img src="$urlboxUrl" />
```

For e.g. here's a urlbox url that will generate a full height screenshot of this very page:

https://api.urlbox.io/v1/ca482d7e-9417-4569-90fe-80f7c5e1c781/0ad1be1ff7ac16bc295d8b0207c98e776003e53e/png?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4235638%2Fhow-to-take-thumbnail-screenshots-of-websites-using-php&full_page=true&thumb_width=400

and here is the resulting screenshot (heavily compressed via imgur :/)

[image: full page screenshot of stackoverflow.com question powered by urlbox.io]

Answer (score 0):

wget can get you where you want to be.  if you can get to a terminal, [websnapr.com](http://www.websnapr.com/support/) is pretty easy to use.  you'll want to register for a key, but they're pretty straightforward to use.

```
wget -O MYFILENAME.png http://images.websnapr.com/?url=MYURL&size=s&nocache=82&key=MYKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, PhantomJS is a browser that can be easily put on a server and integrate it to php. You can find the code in WDudes. They have included lot more features like specifying the image size, cache, download as a file or display in img src etc.

```
<img src=”screenshot.php?url=google.com” />
```

URL Parameters

- Width and Height: screenshot.php?url=google.com&w=1000&h=800
- With cropping:
  screenshot.php?url=google.com&w=1000&h=800&clipw=800&cliph=600
- Disable cache and load fresh screesnhot:
  screenshot.php?url=google.com&cache=0
- To download the image instead of displaying:
  screenshot.php?url=google.com&download=true

You can see the tutorial here: [Capture Screenshot of a Website using PHP without API](http://www.wdudes.com/capture-screenshot-website-using-php-without-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another option to the mix, a service I built for this very purpose that is free for basic usage - [**URL Sensei**](https://urlsensei.com). It provides an API so you can make requests to get screenshot URLs that are hosted on a CDN for you. It is built using Phantom/SlimerJS - but the hard part was making it fast and compressing it reliably. Let me know what you think!